# Using a variable from another script in the same document (apps scripting)

Tags: google-apps-script, global-variables

I am trying to access a variable from another script A.gs in script B.gs. they are both in the same document. How could I do this?

I am not sure how I should solve this problem, I am a beginner with apps scripting and I can't find anything on the internet about it.

```
code.gs:

ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
function onOpen () {
    A = prompt('Hello');
}

code2.gs:

function onOpen () {
    if (A === "123") {
       ui.alert('Hello')
    }
}
```

I want `Hello` to be output if `123` is entered into the prompt, but when I try to run the code I get the error:

`ReferenceError: "A" is not defined. (line 3, file "code2")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In your situation, `code.gs` and `code2.gs` are in a project of a container-bound script type of Google Document.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Modification points:

In your script, the scripts of `code.gs` and `code2.gs` are used as one project at the script editor. So in your script, there are 2 same functions of `onOpen()` in the project. In this case, only one of them is run. In your case, `onOpen()` of `code2.gs` is run and the error of `ReferenceError: "A" is not defined.` occurs.

### Modified script:

If you want to modify your script and you want to work the functions when the Google Document is opened, how about the following modification?

#### 1. Copy and paste the following script to `code.gs` and `code2.gs` of the script editor:

code.gs:

```
var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
function installedOnOpen () {
    A = prompt('Hello'); // or ui.prompt('Hello').getResponseText();
    sample(A);
}
```

code2.gs:

```
function sample (A) {
    if (A === "123") {
       ui.alert('Hello')
    }
}
```

Or, if you want to run independently 2 functions, how about the following modification? In this modification, the value is saved using PropertiesService.

code.gs:

```
var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
function installedOnOpen () {
    A = prompt('Hello'); // or ui.prompt('Hello').getResponseText();
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("key", A);
}
```

code2.gs:

```
function sample () {
    var A = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("key");
    if (A === "123") {
       ui.alert('Hello')
    }
}
```

Or, you can also modify as follows. But, in your situation, this might not be required.

```
function installedOnOpen () {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  var A = ui.prompt('Hello').getResponseText();
  if (A === "123") {
    ui.alert('Hello');
  }
}
```

#### 2. Install OnOpen event trigger:

In order to run the function of `installedOnOpen` when the Google Document is opened, [please install the OnOpen event trigger to the funciton of `installedOnOpen` as the installable trigger.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)

#### 3. Run script:

In your case, there are 2 patterns for running script.

Pattern 1:

Open Google Document.

Pattern 2:

Run `installedOnOpen` at the script editor.

By above, `installedOnOpen` is run. And you can see the dialog at Google Document.

### Note:

- This modification supposes that the function of `prompt()` returns the value of `123` as the string value.

  - If you cannot provide the script of `prompt()`, as a test case, how about modifying from `prompt('Hello');` to `ui.prompt('Hello').getResponseText();`?

### References:

- [Access a variable across multiple script file under a GAS project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57780760)

  - Also I think that this thread might be useful for you.
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! A few hours after posting this question I realized I could do this, and it worked.

Comment: @Batchguy Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you define `onOpen` twice. It does not make sense.

You also don't declare variables and this is reflected in the style of your code. Try declaring the variables and you will realize that your code has no effect.